# How do I make object drop incrementally? LUA

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I can make my object drop incrementally once, but it won't continue to drop down after the first button push. How do I make the image object drop by 50 px , every time I push the button?

```
 local homer = display.newImage ("homer.png", 100, 20)

 local button = display.newImage ("button.png",260,460)
 local buttonText = display.newText ("Push ME =)", 260, 370, nil, 20)

 local spikes = display.newImage ("spikes.png",100 , 500)



 function drop ()
homer: removeSelf ()
homer = display.newImage ("homer.png", 100,20)
homer.y = homer.y + 70 -- How to drop homer incrementally continuously

end


button : addEventListener ("tap", drop)
```

Comment: Why are you removing the image and instantiating it every time?

Comment: Thank You, I guess I was over thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the object's y in the handler, everything else is good:

```
function drop ()
    homer.y = homer.y + 70
end
```